# What does "C:0" mean in file path?

Tags: windows-server-2012, monitoring

I'm trying to troubleshoot high disk I/O that I can see through SQL Server resource monitor. I opened resource monitor to understand what files were causing high disk I/O but path in file column made me more confused. Files that are showing up in `C:0` and `C:2` are on Drive M and Drive L inside mounted volumes that reside in those drives. So I was expecting to see `M:\MountedVolumeName\FileName` instead I see `C:0\FileName` and `C:2\Filename`

I have another SQL Server instance that is also using files from mounted volumes on same drives but those appear as `\Device\HarddiskVolumeXX\Filename`

[image]