# What does D:2 mean as the drive in a Windows path?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, drive-letters

A Windows 2012 server is showing paths starting with D: and with D:2 in Resource Monitor, e.g.:

```
System        4      D:2\$LogFile
sqlservr.exe  1808   D:2\SQL\LOG\Sp2013_Config_log.ldf
```

[Screen capture from the Disk pane of Resource Monitor showing file paths starting with "D:2\"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlOrf.png)

What does it mean when a path begins with "D:2\" rather than "D:\"? Is this particular to Resource Monitor?

I found this similar question, [What does "C:0" mean in file path?](https://serverfault.com/questions/627362/what-does-c0-mean-in-file-path), but I don't think we are using mounted volumes as in that question and it hasn't been answered anyway.

Assuming it is related to mounted volumes, I found this thread on TechNet that supports the suggestion that it is related to both mounted volumes and Resource Monitor but doesn't give any explanation:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9e88df7-cc05-41ae-8e5c-dee9a9654ea5/what-does-c0-in-the-path-mean?forum=winserverfiles

Here is the view from Disk Management as requested:

[Screenshot of Disk Management showing the D: drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjYOq.png)

Answer (score 3):

You are almost certainly using a mounted volume. Post a screenshot of diskmgmt.msc if you'd like confirmation.

Comment: Yes, please - posted.

Comment: Can you show *all* disks? There seem to be a bunch that aren't on the screenshot you sent.

Comment: Sure - I'd hoped just the D: drive would suffice, but I've updated the screenshot to show all drives.

Comment: Does my updated screenshot confirm the presence of mounted volumes? If you could explain what I should be looking for or link to some documentation I can accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I assume that this output from `mountvol D: /L` confirms that the server has mounted volumes: `\\?\Volume{48ff3e96-756e-4f22-838b-113a62c10886}`, but I still can't find any documentation explaining the `D:2` in the path in displayed in Resource Monitor.